# Angular Js and SignalR not working when called from WebAPI and Hub

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am working on signalR implementation with Angular JS. When i tried to call SignalR event from API or Hub to ui client side.. it is not working as expected.
[WebAPI Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGmiH.png)
I am not getting any response in browser for SignalR request.
[ServiceCreated for SignalR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqgTe.png)
[Resposne On Event at client side][3]

I am not getting any resposne in test event for SignalR(Working some times in chrome).

Thanks for advance. Really Appreciate you quick answer.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the connection, additional to that you have to write your the "test" - function on the client which the server calls.

Here you see a sample:

Client Code:

```
<script>

$(function () {
    var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:27709/signalr");
    var chatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
    chatHubProxy.on('newMessageAdded', function (name, message) {
    $("#messages").append("<li>" + name + message + "</li>");
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
    });

connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {
    $('#btnSend').click(function () {
    chatHubProxy.invoke('newMessage', "Stephan", $('#msg').val());
    $('#msg').val('').focus();
    });    
});

});

</script>
```

Server:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
    public void NewMessage(string name, string message)
    {
    Clients.All.newMessageAdded(name, message);
    }
 }
```

It's important that the you write the methode/function on server and client side same (no spelling mistakes).

Attention on Pascal and Camelcase of hubs, methods, ...:
- On the client the proxy name is a camel-cased version of the Hub class name.

By the way: Why you're not using the generated proxy?